# Oracle: Function inside a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a hotel management system. Every time a customer book a room, a row will be inserted into TAKEN with `takenid`, `customerid`, `roomid` and `startday`. Then every product the customer uses within that room will have a row be inserted into `SALE` table for later billing. Finally when the customer checks out a row will be inserted into `BILL` table that has the previous `takenid` and `endday` for calculating the total amount that customers have to pay through a view.
The view I want to create including columns like

*roomnumber*(lookup `roomid` in the `ROOM` table),

*startday*(in TAKEN table),*endday*(in `BILL` table) ,

*employeename*(lookup `employid` in the `EMPLOYEE` table),

*totalproductprice*(by calculating all the product sold in the SALE table base on `takenid`),

*total*(Total amount have to pay)

Which makes the complexity of this view beyond my SQL joining table ability so I decided to use functions to return values as these columns just like in MySQL. I wonder if there is a way to do this in Oracle?

[image: Here is how my database look like]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjxmp.htm#ADOBJ00903 have you read this?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-web-api-with-oracle-database-and-dapper/ this may give you a proper idea

Comment: PLease share what you have tried

Comment: There are a lot of questions about hotel management software the last few days.  What is the difference between totalproductprice and total?

Comment: total = totalproductprice + totalroomprice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view as follow:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_HOTEL_MANAGEMENT AS
SELECT R.roomno, t.startday,e.name,
       (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM SALE 
       WHERE TAKENID = T.TAKENID 
       GROUP BY TAKENID) TOTALPRODUCTPRICE,
       ((SELECT TRUNC(B.ENDDAY - T.STARTDAY)*RT.PRICE 
         FROM BILL B, ROOMTYPE RT, ROOM R 
         WHERE r.type = rt.type 
         AND r.roomid = b.billid 
         AND b.takenid = T.TAKENID 
         AND B.EMPLOYID = E.EMPLOYID)
       +  (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM SALE 
           WHERE TAKENID = T.TAKENID 
           GROUP BY TAKENID)) TOTAL
FROM ROOM R, TAKEN T, EMPLOYEES E
WHERE t.roomid = r.roomid;
```